# Swift Error: Editor placeholder in source file

Tags: ios, swift, class

Hello I am implementing a graph data structure. When I try to build the application the I get the error "Editor placeholder in source file"

The full graph implementation was pulled from WayneBishop's GitHub from here https://github.com/waynewbishop/SwiftStructures

```
class Path {

var total: Int!
var destination: Node
var previous: Path!

init(){
    //Error happens on next line
    destination = Node(key: String?, neighbors: [Edge!], visited: Bool, lat: Double, long: Double)
     }
}
```

I changed the `Node` Class around to:

```
public class Node{

var key: String?
var neighbors: [Edge!]
var visited: Bool = false
var lat: Double
var long: Double

init(key: String?, neighbors: [Edge!], visited: Bool, lat: Double, long: Double) {
    self.neighbors = [Edge!]()
     }

}
```

This Error happens 5 times throughout the code that I have built so far. Also this question has been asked, but not answered.

I think the error may be due to my changes to the `init()` in the `Node` class. Prior to my changes it was just `init()`. If it is, how can I add objects to the class? Pardon me if I am not correct in my programming terminology, as I am relatively new to OOP.

Comment: Yeah (Cmd + shift + K) Thug Life !!!!

Comment: @AhmetAkkök I don't know what you did to create such an issue, but this error *currently* has NOTHING to do with what you suggest. His code is `Node(key: String?` <-- He simply has to insert instead of `String`?. It's expecting a value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you had this

```
destination = Node(key: String?, neighbors: [Edge!], visited: Bool, lat: Double, long: Double)
```

which was place holder text  above you need to insert some values

```
class Edge{

}

public class Node{

  var key: String?
  var neighbors: [Edge]
  var visited: Bool = false
  var lat: Double
  var long: Double

  init(key: String?, neighbors: [Edge], visited: Bool, lat: Double, long: Double) {
    self.neighbors = [Edge]()
    self.key = key
    self.visited = visited
    self.lat = lat
    self.long = long
  }

}

class Path {

  var total: Int!
  var destination: Node
  var previous: Path!

  init(){
    destination = Node(key: "", neighbors: [], visited: true, lat: 12.2, long: 22.2)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 93):

Sometimes, XCode does not forget the line which had an "Editor Placeholder" even if you have replaced it with a value. Cut the portion of the code where XCode is complaining and paste the code back to the same place to make the error message go away. This worked for me.

Comment: I found cut/paste didnt work sufficiently, but rebuilding did the trick.  Product -> Build Clean Folder, Product -> Build

Comment: Cut and pasting the line on same line silenced "Editor placeholder in source file". The error started after I paste a middle sized block of code.

Answer (score 30):

After Command + Shift + B, the project works fine.

Answer (score 21):

Go to **Product** > **Clean Build Folder**

Answer (score 1):

Error is straight forward and its because of wrong placeholders you have used in function call. Inside `init` you are not passing any parameters to your function. It should be this way

```
destination = Node("some key", neighbors: [edge1 , edge2], visited: true, lat: 23.45, long: 45.67) // fill up with your dummy values
```

Or you can just initialise with default method

```
destination = Node()
```

**UPDATE**

Add empty initialiser in your Node class

```
init() {

}
```

Comment: so dummy values need to be placed in the initializer in order for them to compile?

Comment: Its not dummy value, you need to initialise with data available with you at that time. If not you can pass empty data. Else use second way around to initialise

Comment: I tried that and it returns an error "Cannot Invoke Initializer for Type 'Node' with no arguments`

Comment: returns error Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass......Could this have anything to do with Inheritance? Maybe move the destination to another file/class?

Comment: okay I added an empty initializer, but it errors out with "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties" unless I fill in dummy values for the variables. Do I need to keep it that way? If so, how do I add a new object?

Comment: You can set which ever data is available at that point of time. To remove that error, declare your vars optional i.e `var neighbors: [String!]!` `var lat: Double!` `var long: Double!`

Comment: So with this, how can I add a new object? Right now I cannot say var hello = Node(key: "hey"...). is it through overrides?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This works for me:

1. Product -> Build Clean Folder
2. Product -> Build

Answer (score 0):

Clean Build folder
+
Build

will clear any error you may have even after fixing your code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Item instead of item was causing the problem, here's come with a comment

```
struct AspectVGrid<Item, ItemView>: View where ItemView: View, Item: Identifiable {
    var items: [Item]
    var aspectRatio: CGFloat
    var content: (Item) -> ItemView


    var body: some View {
        let width: CGFloat = 100
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: width))]) {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                // using Item instead of item caused the problem
                content(Item).aspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio,
                        contentMode: .fit)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have this error while you create segues with the view controllers not with the UI elements you have to change `sender: Any?` to this

```
@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMainScreen", sender: self)

    }
```

It will work.