# Type "X" has no member of "Y"

Tags: swift, xcode

Edit: Figured out some of my issue. However, why do I have this error now? (See Photo)[image]

I am running into an error that I can't seem to fix. The Error is in my fetchPosts() function. I though this would work since I am using my Post array from my Method Folder, which just has some attributes to it.

```
class UIFeedViewControllerTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var posts: [Post]?


    struct  Storyboard {


    static let postCell = "PostCell"
    static let postHeaderCell = "PostHeaderCell"
    static let postHeaderHeight : CGFloat = 57.0
    static let postCellDefaultHeight : CGFloat = 578.0

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.fetchPosts()

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = Storyboard.postCellDefaultHeight
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clear
    }



        func fetchPosts()
        {
            //this could be from Firebase, Amazon, whatever

           ** self.posts = Post.fetchPosts()**
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

}



extension UIFeedViewControllerTableViewController {
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        if let posts = posts {
            return posts.count
        }
        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let _ = posts {
            return 1
        } else {
        return 0

    }
}

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.postCell, for: indexPath) as! PostCell

        cell.Post = self.posts?[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        return cell
    }

}
```

It states that my Error is "Type 'Post' has no member 'fetchPosts' Any help would be great!

Comment: Where's the `Post` class? Can you post its code? Does it have a `fetchPosts` static method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frankenstein mentioned, you're calling a function on the Type itself, not an instance of the type. In other words, you're not calling any sort of variable or constant instance, you're calling the Type definition (the blueprint) itself. And that's not allowed unless you explicitly state it in the type.

Sometimes you want this, but then you have to make the `fetchPosts` function in the `Post` type static. Like:

```
struct Post { // or maybe your Post type is a class, so it would be class Post {
    ...
    static func fetchPosts() { ... }
    ...
}
```

But I'm guessing you don't actually want to run a static function on the Type itself, because it would have no access to any of the properties of any `Post` struct/class that you created and populated with settings/data in the properties.

It's hard to tell how to help without seeing exactly what's going with your `Post` type.

But I'd guess you actually want to create an instance of `Post` first. Something like:

```
func fetchPosts()
{
    //this could be from Firebase, Amazon, whatever

    var postInstance = Post() // This creates a new Post instance for you to work with
    self.posts = postInstance.fetchPosts() // This calls your new Post instance's fetchPost() method
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

That will make your error go away, but I'm not sure you want to run `fetchPosts` on a brand new instance of `Post`. Did you already have a `Post` instance somewhere that needs to be accessed in this scope?

And is it just a coincidence that you have a `fetchPosts()` method in both your `Post` class/struct AND in your `UIFeedViewControllerTableViewController` class?

Comment: Please check the screenshot I added, I am doing a YouTube Tutorial and don't know how to finish it. The video cuts off the solution at the bottom.

Comment: So is the original issue resolved? Could you mark mine as answered?

As for the new error, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167123/swift-error-editor-placeholder-in-source-file

Answer (score -1):

You are using the `Post.fetchPosts()` as though it is static. Either make it `static` or call `fetchPosts()` on an instance of `Post`.

```
struct Post {
    ...
    static func fetchPosts() { ...
```

I wouldn't recommend either way is not recommended either of these methods because, Post seems to be data model and you are trying to fetch the same model from within itself. Moving the `fetchPost()` to the `Controller` would be better. Moving it to a `dataSource` would be best.